# javax.jcr.* javadocs are missing

Tags: java, aem, jcr

I have noticed that `javadocs` for `javax.jcr` are missing. All pages storing this, that I know, show 404 now.

Examples:

- [link1](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html)
- [link2](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/Node.html)
- [link3](http://www.day.com/maven/jdiff-jcr1-jcr2/changes/javax.jcr.Node.html)

Any news about it? Is there any other place where I can find `javadocs` for `javax.jcr.*` ?

Comment: I found a copy in the wayback machine: https://archive.org/web/

Answer (score 2):

You can find the documentation on the JCP site: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/contentrepository-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/